# Did my wildlife camera take a picture of a lynx?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, feline

A wildlife camera took a photograph of an animal. Unfortunately this is the only picture my camera collected. This picture was taken in the central interior of British Columbia, Canada. The distance from the camera to the subject is a few meters, and the height of the camera off the ground was probably about 40 - 50 cm.

[image]

Is this animal a lynx? It looks like it might have those fine tufts on its ears and a reduced tail.

---

While I generally try to avoid cross-posting, I have started pooling my observations into iNaturalist. This photo can be found as [Observation 110929888](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/110929888).

Comment: Any chance of examining the area for tracks?

Comment: No, unfortunately the snow was quite icy and compacted; found no tracks.

Comment: How about markings on the tree trunk? IIRC lynx will sometimes scratch the bark as part of marking their territory ...

Comment: I didn't notice, but I wasn't looking for that. Interesting ethology fact though. I'll take a look at the trees in the area when I return to the location.

Comment: I thought that those cameras take a photo every second when something starts moving. It's facing towards the light as well so with the snow, it's too bright. The silhouette is definitely that of a lynx though, small tail, strong hind quarters, it looks like 90% probability it's a lynx

Comment: I have not played with the settings on this camera, but I recall from the manual that I can control the rate. I don't recall what it is currently set to, but I have a feeling it isn't as a frequent as every second; something I should correct.

Comment: As with [your other trail camera question about coyote](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/93010/16866), some (fairly accurate) size estimate of the tree or other foliage in the picture may help. Lynx are typically larger than bobcats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is either a [Canada lynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada_lynx) or a [bobcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobcat).

From wikipedia:

> The lynx is between 73 and 107 cm (29 and 42 in) in head-and-body length and stands 48–56 cm (19–22 in) tall at the shoulder; females weigh around 5–12 kg (11–26 lb) while males weigh around 6–17 kg (13–37 lb).

> The adult bobcat is 47.5 to 125 cm (18.7 to 49.2 in) long from the head to the base of its distinctive stubby tail, averaging 82.7 cm (32.6 in); the tail is 9 to 20 cm (3.5 to 7.9 in) long. Its "bobbed" appearance gives the species its name. An adult stands about 30 to 60 cm (12 to 24 in) at the shoulders.

Without a clearer image or a better sense of scale I cannot say which. Their silhouette is just too similar.